# How do I get an encryption to work cross browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, encryption

I have created a page that encrypts two fields and sends it to another page where it is decrypted.

The problem is if I make my submit button send an smtp email to the user (rather than to page2.aspx itself) and they open the page in any other browser than the one that it was encrypted in, it no longer works.

For example: On page1.aspx there is an ID field, an email field, and a submit button. On submit it encrypts the ID field and sends it as a link (page2.aspx?query=ENCRYPTED DATA) where I can view the data. (This works if I stay in a specific browser)

The problem is I get a bad data error when I open the link in another browser. (Encrypted in Firefox then opening the link in Google Chrome) It throws the Bad Data server error.

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue? I want to be able to open the link from an email but allow cross browser activity using the encrypted link. Any solutions would be great. Thanks.

Here is the Encryption:

```
public string Encrypt(string message)
{
    UTF8Encoding textConverter = new UTF8Encoding();
    RC2CryptoServiceProvider rc2CSP = new RC2CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] toEncrypt = textConverter.GetBytes(message);

    ICryptoTransform encryptor = rc2CSP.CreateEncryptor(ScrambleKey, ScrambleIV);
    MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    byte[] length = new byte[4];
    length[0] = (byte)(message.Length & 0xFF);
    length[1] = (byte)((message.Length >> 8) & 0xFF);
    length[2] = (byte)((message.Length >> 16) & 0xFF);
    length[3] = (byte)((message.Length >> 24) & 0xFF);
    csEncrypt.Write(length, 0, 4);
    csEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
    csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
    string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    string b64mod = b64.Replace('+', '@');
    return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(b64mod);
}
```

Here is the Email:

```
private void AutomatedEmail()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString4"].ConnectionString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rd = null;
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID WHERE ID = @ID", con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", lblid.InnerText);
    rd = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (rd.Read())
    {
        string Query = "http://page2.aspx?query=" + Encrypt("ID=" + (rd["ID"].ToString()));

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(rd["OwnerEmail"].ToString());
        message.From = new MailAddress("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        message.Subject = "Test Email";
        message.Body = "Test: " + Query;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("xxxx");
        smtp.Port = xxxx;
        smtp.EnableSsl = false;
        NetworkCredential netcre = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx");
        smtp.Credentials = netcre;
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

*******EDIT*******

Keys for Encryption/Decryption:

```
public byte[] ScrambleKey
{
    set
    {
        byte[] key = value;
        if (null == key)
        {
            key = ScrambleKey;
        }
        Session["ScrambleKey"] = key;
    }
    get
    {
        byte[] key = (byte[])Session["ScrambleKey"];
        if (null == key)
        {
            RC2CryptoServiceProvider rc2 = new RC2CryptoServiceProvider();
            rc2.GenerateKey();
            key = rc2.Key;
            Session["ScrambleKey"] = key;
        }
        return key;
    }
}
public byte[] ScrambleIV
{
    set
    {
        byte[] key = value;
        if (null == key)
        {
            key = ScrambleIV;
        }
        Session["ScrambleIV"] = key;
    }
    get
    {
        byte[] key = (byte[])Session["ScrambleIV"];
        if (null == key)
        {
            RC2CryptoServiceProvider rc2 = new RC2CryptoServiceProvider();
            rc2.GenerateIV();
            key = rc2.IV;
            Session["ScrambleIV"] = key;
        }
        return key;
    }
}
```

Receiving Page: Decryption:

```
public string Decrypt(string scrambledMessage)
{
    UTF8Encoding textConverter = new UTF8Encoding();
    RC2CryptoServiceProvider rc2CSP = new RC2CryptoServiceProvider();

    string b64mod = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(scrambledMessage);
    string b64 = b64mod.Replace('@', '+');
    byte[] encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);

    ICryptoTransform decryptor = rc2CSP.CreateDecryptor(ScrambleKey, ScrambleIV);
    MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(encrypted);
    CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    byte[] fromEncrypt = new byte[encrypted.Length - 4];
    byte[] length = new byte[4];
    csDecrypt.Read(length, 0, 4);
    csDecrypt.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);
    int len = (int)length[0] | (length[1] << 8) | (length[2] << 16) | (length[3] << 24);
    return textConverter.GetString(fromEncrypt).Substring(0, len);
}
public NameValueCollection DecryptQueryString(string scrambledMessage)
{
    string queryString = Decrypt(scrambledMessage);

    NameValueCollection result = new NameValueCollection();
    char[] splitChar = new char[] { '&' };
    char[] equalChar = new char[] { '=' };
    foreach (string s in queryString.Split(splitChar))
    {
        string[] keyVal = s.Split(equalChar, 2);
        string key = keyVal[0];
        string val = String.Empty;
        if (keyVal.Length > 1) val = keyVal[1];
        result.Add(key, val);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Source Error: Line 112.

```
Line 110: byte[] length = new byte[4];
Line 111: csDecrypt.Read(length, 0, 4);
Line 112: csDecrypt.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);
Line 113: int len = (int)length[0] | (length[1] << 8) | (length[2] << 16) | (length[3] << 24);
Line 114: return textConverter.GetString(fromEncrypt).Substring(0, len);
```

Comment: I don't understand what the browser has to do with anything, since this seems to be entirely server-side code.

Comment: The issue is when trying to open the link after the email has been sent out to the user. Say I use IE and the recipient of the email uses Google Chrome. When the Google Chrome user opens the link, it throws a Bad Data error on Google Chrome. However, if I use Google Chrome and the recipient uses Google Chrome, the link in the email works and the query string is decrypted, as it should be. I posted code for reference. The code works fine. I am just encountering issues when the users are using different browsers than I am. I am trying to find a cause and a solution.

Comment: I understand how you are reproducing the problem, but since the code you have posted here does not interact with the user's browser in any way, the problem does not lie in this code. Have you thoroughly ruled out other factors such as time delays, session/cookie data (try the same browser, but in a "private"/"incognito" window)? You also haven't shown the receiving code which is actually giving this "Bad Data error".

Comment: The link did not work in a private window. I have posted the receiving code and the source error.

Comment: They keys are being stored in the Session, which is browser dependent.

Comment: Why are you not just using SSL on your site?  What's the point of doing this encryption?

Comment: If you really don't want to rely on SSL for whatever reasons ... you could encrypt the key or the session id on the server side and include it in the url ala kerberos? Needless to say that the url will become highly sensitive, if you send the url via email you will most likely have to encrypt the email as well. You should clarify your requirements, it is hard to advise you without knowing what you are trying to achieve.